# gIntersection function alternatives in R

Tags: r, math

I'd like to know if there are any alternatives to the gIntersection function in R. When trying to run my script on our remote server (Ubuntu), I noticed that I needed some dependencies for the rgeos package and unfortunately, I'm not on the sudoers list :(

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Have you done your required searching on SO: `[r] intersect polygons`

Comment: I did try the Intersect method in the gpclib package, however, the results that it returned weren't intersect coordinates, but rather the max height of the larger polygon and the range of the x axis. thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: You can do it without sudo privs but it would mean compiling the GEOS library of C/C++ from its source code, and then telling R that GEOS is in /home/me/stuff/GEOS or wherever when you install the rgeos package.. Its not *that* hard but its more things to go wrong. Asking your admins to install it is easier (but getting the answer you want is harder).

Comment: @Spacedman I've downloaded the packages for 'sp' and 'rgeos' so they can be installed in R, but rgeos won't install due to the GEOS dependency problem. So I downloaded the GEOS source, compiled it on the server './configure  &&  make', but where in the 'install.packages' command would I specify that a dependency is somewhere else?

Comment: just in case anyone else has this problem, this is how I used the package without root permission. This is by no means a permanent solution.
1/. Download source of dependent package
2/. Run configure, make and then make install
3/. Add the binary for the user path and add the lib folder of the compiled package to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
4/. Install the package in R - This requires that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH which makes this a not so sustainable technique.